# Linearly independent numbers problem

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{aligned}r_{i}\in
\mathbb{Q}\quad r_{1},r_{2},\ldots ,r_{n}\in\left( 0,1\right) \\
Proof：2^{r_{1}},\ldots ,2^{r_{n}}\ \text{is linearly independent on }  \mathbb{Q}
\end{aligned}
Some hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

$x^n-2$ is an Eisenstein polynomial so is irreducible. Thus $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[n]2)=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^n-2)$ is a degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb Q$. In particular, $1,\sqrt[n]2,\sqrt[n]2^2,\dots,\sqrt[n]2^{n-1}$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent.